# How can I use CoreML with iOS AVCAptureDelegate Camera for my OWN model?

Tags: ios, swift, model, avcapturesession, coreml

So basically I got some models from Apple's website specifically SqueezeNet and it worked. However, now I want to apply my own model for it to predict. How can I do it?

My model is Mask Detection and has two classes: with mask, with no mask.

My questions are:

1. How can I do that?
2. Why it works on SqueezeNet but not my model?
3. I don't know if the photos I receive from `CVPixelBuffer` will automatically be converted to arrays by CoreMl or I have to do it myself?

Right now there is CIFAR model that has 10 classes. It can't predict objects right now as well.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
    var result = String()
    
    //ALL THE OBJECTS
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // 1 - start session
        let capture_session = AVCaptureSession()
        //capture_session.sessionPreset = .vga640x480
        
        // 2 - set the device front & add input
        guard let capture_device = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) else {return}
        
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: capture_device) else { return }
        if capture_session.canAddInput(input) {
            capture_session.addInput(input)
        }
        
        // 3 - the layer on screen that shows the picture
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: capture_session)
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame.size = CGSize(width: SVWidth, height: SVWidth)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        
        // 4 - the produced output aka image or video
        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
        if capture_session.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
            capture_session.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }
    
        // 5 - run the session
        capture_session.startRunning()
    }
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
        
        // our model
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: CIFAR(configuration: MLModelConfiguration()).model) else { return }
        
        // request for our model
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedReq, err) in
            if let error = err {
                print("failed to detect faces:", error)
                return
                
            }
            
            guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {return}
            guard let first_observation = results.last else {return}
            
            self.delegate?.clasificationOccured(self, identifier: first_observation.identifier)
            
            //self.result = first_observation.identifier
            //print(self.result)
            
        }
        guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {return}
        try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you believe it doesn't work for your model. Right now there is not enough information for debugging the issue.